# Converting .tif to XYZ in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, convert, geotiff-tiff, xyz

How can I convert a .tif DEM to XYZ format using QGIS?

What I have is a geotiff image.  What I need to do is turn that .tif into folders containing several XYZ tiles (like how Google Maps or OpenStreetMaps serves their tiles).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201224/convert-raster-to-a-csv-values-and-lat-long-based-on-raster-value-in-qgis

Answer (score 9):

In QGIS, go to `Processing toolbox` / `GDAL/OGR` / `[GDAL] Conversion` / `gdal2xyz`

This tool will extract *x*, *y* and *z* to a comma separate values file (.csv).

[image: gdal]

---

**EDIT:**

1) results is a *.csv* file. If you want to convert it to *.txt*, just open file.csv in excel an click en `save as... / Text - tab delimited .(txt)`

---

2) to export to a .xyz file.

n QGIS, go to `Processing toolbox` / `GDAL/OGR` / `[GDAL] Conversion` / `Translate (convert format)`

Go to `Save to file...` and select `XYZ files (*.xyz)`

In your case, from [GMT documentation](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/doc/latest/xyz2grd.html):

> **Examples**
>
> To create a grid file from the ASCII data in hawaii_grv.xyz,
>   use
>
> ```
> gmt xyz2grd hawaii_grv.xyz -Ddegree/degree/mGal/1/0//”Hawaiian Gravity”/”GRS-80 Ellipsoid used”
>    -Ghawaii_grv_new.nc -R198/208/18/25 -I5m -V
> ```

[image: xyz]

Comment: is this good to plot a map with GMT?

Comment: I've never use GMT, only QGIS for cartography. Which kind of input do you need for GMT?

Comment: I also never use GMT, I use Arcgis and QGIS for cartography but someone request me x,y,z to plot a map with GMT.  He told me that .txt and.prj it´s ok for him but I don´t know if .csv can run

Comment: I edit my answer, take a look.