# GDAL remove nodatavalues from output for COG format

Tags: gdal, merge, nodata

I need to remove the nodata values from the final mosaic of Sentinel-2 data.

Here is the process I apply to each single file:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -srcnodata 0 input.jp2 output_warp.tif
gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co TILED=YES -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS output_warp.tif <file_name>_final.tif
```

Once I have transformed all single files, I need to merge them all together to create a mosaic. Therefore, I apply the following commands:

```
gdalbuildvrt output_merged.vrt *final.tif
gdal_translate -of COG -co BIGTIFF=YES -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS output_merged.vrt output_merged.tif
```

However, I get a final mosaic that has nodatavalues included. Here is the resulting image:

[image]

I tried several methods to remove nodata, but no way to get rid of them.

Using the command:

```
gdal_edit.py -unsetnodata merged_prova.tif
```

I got this (visualized in QGIS where background is white):

[image]

I don't understand if it applied a black background to the image, but it is not what I need. I would like to remove the background completely.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the command or option that you use for removing the nodata value?

Comment: I tried to apply the method described here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/201232. Also, I tried other methods I found on the internet. No way to remove them, though. The problem seems the JPEG compression. If I use COMPRESS=LWZ I don't have the nodatavalues (or at least I don't see them in the final mosaic. The problem is that LWZ brings me a mosaic of about 9GB, compared with JPEG which is about 500MB.

Comment: Sorry, I understood your question in a quite opposite way: how to remove the nodata value from the image metadata so that none of the pixels is transparent. But instead you want to keep the nodata value and the transparent background, but do something for making the border between the  data and background sharp. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely right. I want to remove the black residual pixels.

Comment: You found the reason for your issue yourself. Using nodata (marking one pixel value to mean not-existing data) is not a perfect method, rather a workaround for software which do not support presenting validity with a mask band or an alpha band. JPEG is a lossy compression method that is designed to create small files which look good for the eye. Lossy means that it is not guaranteed that the pixel values in the source data remains the same in compression. Black pixels with value 0 can have a value 1 or 2 after compression. They still look black but they have lost the nodata meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gdal_edit.py` with `-unsetnodata` which removes existing no data values. [Check out the gdal_edit manual here](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html)

Comment: I tried also this solution... no way.

Comment: I get all black in background. The command I did is:
gdal_edit.py -unsetnodata merged_20230929_nomask_prova.tif

Comment: Have you tried to assign the no data value? -a_nodata using gdal_translate? Additionally there may be multiple in a Sentinel 2 image such as 0 and 1.

Comment: I am working on the TCI band. As you can see at the beginning, I used the command
 gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -srcnodata 0 input.jp2 output_warp.tif
  I got this from gdalinfo on the output tile:
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=0

Comment: If you click 'identify' or the 'i' icon on a black pixel what does it show in the results? Does is say 'no data' or is there a numeric value?

Comment: I get Band 1, 2, and 3 all 0

Comment: Yes, the identify features button. Make sure you are reading from the merged raster layer

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. It is indeed a 0 value. But I am observing the result of the gdal_edit.py -unsetnodata file. On the original file (the one obtained with the process described above) I have indeed 1.

Comment: Okay so run gdal_translate -a_nodata 1 on your original file and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this way all back pixels are now white but all nodata are now back. Like a negative even though the tiles are still correctly displayed. Coming back to the info on the original mosaic, I noticed that there are numeric values but not always 1...

Comment: Okay yes so as I was saying in a previous comment, you have two values that need to be recoded to no data, likely the values 0 and 1. gdal_translate -a_nodata only accepts one value so you can use gdal_calc.py instead to recode them. gdal_calc.py -A your_input_raster --calc="A*(A>1.5)+0*(A<1.5)" --outfile=your_output_file. This outputs a file with the raster values from your input layer for all values above 1.5 but any values below 1.5 are recoded to 0. then you can run gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 on the output to get what you want.

Comment: Did you change the no data values on the original dataset by using the above command?

Answer (score 0):

Your original problem was caused by `gdal_translate` to JPEG compressed geotiffs before merging i.e. `gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG etc... output_warp.tif <file_name>_final.tif`.

JPEG is a lossy compression type and you will alter the rasters values so you will get areas that should be zero (i.e NoData) but are actually close to zero (i.e. 1, 2 or 3 etc.) which means they start showing up. So you don't want to use JPEG compression until you produce the very final output.

Alpha mask relies on having NoData value correctly set to begin with. So make sure you run `gdalbuildvrt` on the output of your original `gdalwarp` from jp2, not on the `gdal_translate` JPEG compressed outputs or otherwise processed files.

You don't even need to `gdal_warp` to tiff, you can output a vrt instead then run `gdalbuildvrt` on the individual vrt outputs.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -srcnodata 0 input.jp2 output_warp.vrt
```

Then use an alpha mask band

E.g given the two rasters "test1.tif" and "test2.tif" below (or VRTs, but *not* JPEG compressed tiffs).

[image]

Build a VRT with the [`-addalpha`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html#cmdoption-gdalbuildvrt-addalpha) option:

```
gdalbuildvrt -addalpha test.vrt test1.tif test2.tif
```

Convert to COG.

```
gdal_translate -of COG -co compress=JPEG test.vrt test.tif
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, in this way, I get black squares around each tile as per the original projection. It seems more difficult than expected. See the post above.

Comment: Alpha mask relies on having NoData value correctly set to begin with. Make sure you run gdalbuildvrt on the output of your original gdalwarp from jp2, not on any other gdal_translate outputs or otherwse processed files. You don't even need to gdal_warp to tiff, you can output a vrt instead then run gdalbuildvrt on the individual vrt outputs. Your original problem was caused by gdal_translate to JPEG compressed geotiffs before merging.